# zoom in graphic context by a factor around a pivot value

Tags: android, ios, android-canvas, quartz-graphics, cgcontext

I am trying to zoom in my canvas when the user pinches the screen In IOS.

I am translating my code from Android(which works), here's a snift:

```
focusX = gestureDetector.getFocusX();
focusY = gestureDetector.getFocusY();

enter code herecanvas.scale(mScaleFactor,mScaleFactor,focusX,focusY);
```

my translated IOS code doesn't give the same results:

```
- (void)onScale:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
         CGPoint endPoint = [gesture locationInView:self];
         focusX = endPoint.x;
         focusY = endPoint.y;
    }
}

CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), focusX, focusY);
CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor)
```

Why?

Comment: You could post some code here. In general CGContextTranslateCTM and CGContextScaleCTM should do the job. You might be missing something.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, CGContextTranslateCTM is redundant. Also I had another problem , the scale factor of the recognizer in Android is relative whereas in IOS it's absolute.